# How to send image on WEBrtc channel?

Tags: webrtc, channel

I am stuck on sending image via webrtc channel, but I got this error.

> Cannot read property 'files' of undefined at SimpleWebRTC

I need help. Thank you in advance.

```
$("#send-image").change(function() {

    if (this.files && this.files[0]) {

            var reader = new FileReader();

            reader.onload = function(e) {
                $('.output #photo').attr('src', e.target.result);
            }

            reader.readAsDataURL(this.files[0]);

            webrtc.sendDirectlyToAll('shareImage', '');
     }

});
var input = $('#send-image')[0];

if (input.files[0]) {

    var reader = new FileReader();

    reader.onload = function(e) {
        $('.output #photo').attr('src', e.target.result);
    }

    reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);

}
```

Comment: The error message says that you tried to get `undefined.files`, if this is really related code that you shown, then the problem is likely that `input` is undefined, and very probably because at the time you call `$('#send-image')` there is no element with an `id` `"send-image"` in the DOM-tree yet, maybe because you executed this script before this element is declared? Anyway, it's really unlikely that is has anything to do with webrtc.

Comment: It has id on my input `<input type="file" class="hidden" id="send-image">`. I want to do is only send only the image url to the channel. But if I send the `e.target.result` it says maximum bytes because it is base64.